# remove noise after image segmentation

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have an image that I have segmented through a k-mean clustering algorithm. 
 The output is an INTEGER bidimensional array (same size of the input image) indicating the identified regions. Later on I want to poligonize these regions.

The segmentation output is a little noisy and I would like to filter this out. 
Of course, if I apply filters such as avereging, gaussian, etc. the problem is that I create intermediate array values and therefore an higher number of polygons.

Any ideas, MATLAB built-in function that can help me for my specific problem?

Thanks in advance folks

Comment: [mcve] is important

Comment: use morphological filters

Comment: An alternative to removing noise after segmentation is to remove noise before segmentation. That usually is the best approach. You can apply non-linear filters such as the bilateral filter to preserve edge sharpness.